# sorting structure elements in C

Tags: c

I have the following code, in which I must sort book titles by alphabetical order. this is the code I have and am unsure of how to perform the actual sort. any help regarding how to sort more than 2 books would also be appreciated, because the user is prompted to enter up to 30 books.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct Books
{
    char title[256];
    char author[256];
    char genre[256];
    int qualityRATE;
    int pages;
};

int numberbook = 1;
int casee;
int booksnumber;
int i;

int main()
{
    char again;

    do
    {
        printf("how many books will you be entering today?");
        scanf("%i", &booksnumber);
        printf("Enter the information for your book.\n Name\n Author\n Genre\n quality rating\n\n");
        struct Books book1;
        struct Books book2;
        scanf("%s", book1.title);
        scanf("%s", book2.title);

        printf("The title of book %i is: %s\n", numberbook, book1.title);
        printf("The title of book %i is: %s\n", numberbook, book2.title);

        printf("how would you like to sort?\n 1: By title\n 2: by Author\n 3: by pages\n\n");
        scanf("%i", &casee);
        switch(casee) 
        {
            case 1:
                for(i = 1; i < booksnumber, i++;)
                {
                    if(strcmp(book[i].title, book[i+1].title) < 0)
                        strcpy(book[i+1].title, book[i].title);
                    else
                        if(strcmp(book[i+1].title, book[i].title) < 0)
                            strcpy(book[i].title, book[i+1].title);

                }
                printf("\n%s\n", book1.title);
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
        }

        printf("Another book?\n");
        numberbook++;
        scanf("%s", &again);
    }

    while(again == 'y');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: change to `scanf(" %c", &again);`, also use `qsort`.

Comment: With `qsort` you will need to pass a `comparitor function` as an argument that allows `qsort` to determine which of any 2 books is greater than the other (alphabetically). For alphabetically sorting structures, you can find numerous examples on SO and the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see in your code some problems:

You have to initialize an array of book structures, not book1 and book2, declaring:

```
struct books book[nnn] /* where nnn is the maximum number of book */
```

You have to use a counter (should be booksnumber) starting from 0 into the do while loop

You have to use scanf using book[booksnumber] and increment booksnumber for each scanf.

If you want a solid sort engine I suggest you to use the function qsort (qsort is a C library function in stdlib.h)

see: [www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort)

A correct way to sort the item should be that in the following code:

```
struct Books app;
int i,j;

for(i=0;i<booksnumber;i++) {
       for(j=i+1;j<booksnumber;j++) {
          if (strcmp(book[i].title,book[j].title)<0) {
             app=book[i];
             book[j]=book[i];
             book[i]=app;
          }
       }
    }
```

I think that the first for loop should be better as below, but I have written this code on the fly and then I have not verified its behavour.

```
for(i=0;i<booksnumber-1;i++)
```

I've not verified if the direction of the sort is as you require, if is not you may change the "sign" of the comparation inverting it. IE:

```
if (strcmp(book[i].title,book[j].title)>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

For just two books you can use `swap`. And I think you also need to swap all book properties, not just its title :

```
void swapBook(struct Books *a, struct Books *b) {
    struct Books c = *a; /* backup first book */
    *a = *b; /* replace first book with second book */
    *b = c;  /* replace second book with the backup of first book */
}
```

Then you should be able to use it like this:

```
if ( strcmp(book[i].title, book[i+1].title) < 0 ) {
     swapBook( &book[i], &book[i+1] );
}
```

For more than two books, this is not going to work, you need to use `qsort`.